# Simple topology proof

Tags: general-topology

**Claim:** In a metric space $(X, d)$ the set $X$ is open.

**Proof:**
For each point $a ∈ X$, every open ball centered at $a$ is contained in $X$. Thus $X$ is open.

---

Could someone expound on the proof?

Is it supposed to be a trivial proof, where we know that every open ball centered at $a$ is contained in $X$? If so, how do we know that?

Comment: what is your definition of open?

Comment: Proof and definition are from a book: "To show that a subset A of X is open, it is required to show that if a is a point of A, then a is the center of an open sphere contained in A."

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question, I've been pondering over it for a while but can't grasp it.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking: there is *nothing* outside of $X$. So *any* ball centered at $a\in X$ is contained in $X$, hence $X$ is open.

Comment: @egreg, thank you. That there's nothing outside of $X$ is what I needed to realize..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in a metric space $(X,d)$ the open ball centred at $a \in X$ of radius $r \in \mathbb{R}, r>0$ is by definition (!)

$$B_X(a,r) = \{x \in X: d(x,a) < r \}$$

which is a subset of $X$. It's indeed a triviality from the definition.

E.g. if $X = [0,1]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ ,then $B_X(0,\frac{1}{4}) = [0,\frac{1}{4})$; one has to stick to your space, as it were. And so $[0,1]$ is open in $(X,d)$.

Comment: Thanks. But, man, I keep thinking of cases where the ball might not be contained in X, i.e. have the center inside with "outside" boundaries or something :\ (and X being something small and finite, not R or similar). This should be so easy and I can't grasp it...

Comment: @Max the centre is in the space $X$ too. $d$ is only defined for pairs from $X$ by definition.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, yes, I understood that the center is inside $X$, maybe I didn't word it correctly. I drew a picture: https://i.imgur.com/k2XK1FW.png is it correct? So a ball is all points less than some $r$ _that are actually in the space_.

Comment: Yes, if you look at @Henno's definition it says "$\{x \in X : ...\}$. In your picture, $X$ is the square, so the open ball $B_X$ doesn't include any of the points of the plane outside of the square.

Comment: @JonathanZ, thanks. Yeah I basically thought all points up to $r$ from $a$ should be included, otherwise the ball's not inside the space. Just me not being mathematically mature...

Comment: @Max, you can check my answer below where I think I state it more explicitly.

Comment: And you're right that part of mathematical maturity is knowing what is being implicitly assumed and what might change if we alter those assumptions. Things like this, where you realize, question, and make explicit your assumption are great for gaining that maturity.

Answer (score 1):

A set $S$ in a metric space is open if for each $x\in S$ some $\epsilon$-neighborhood (with $\epsilon>0$) of $x$ is contained in $S.$ If $S=X,$ then any neighborhood of any $x\in X$ is a subset of $X.$

The essential point is that $X$ is the space itself. Any neighborhood consists of points from $X,$ per definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's supposed to be a 'trivial' proof, as it just involves unwinding of definitions.

To be rigorous, we shouldn't say 'set $A$ is open', but 'set $A$ is an open subset of the topological space $X$', i.e. openness depends on what we are considering to be the ambient topological space. We are often lazy and omit mentioning it, or it might be "clear to everyone" so we don't take the time to say what it is, but it is always there.

As an example

$[0,1]$ **is** an open subset of $( [0,1], d)$

$[0,1]$ **is not** an open subset of $( \mathbb{R}, d)$

(where $d$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$).